# Does my company's DUNS number need to be active to renew my Developer Program Membership?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I need to renew my Apple's Developer Program Membership. But my D-U-N-S number (which was required to enrol in the program the first time) has expired.

But it is too expensive, and it is useful for absolutely nothing. So, will Apple check it again in my renew? Do I really need to keep it active?

Answer (score 2):

While Apple does check your DUNS number at registration, it does not need to be active to continue the membership.

I know a company who had their DUNS number expire several years ago but they have still successfully renewed their membership.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pay Dunn & Broadstreet anything - your legal entity just has to be listed when/if Apple checks to verify.

I doubt you'll have issues if you are renewing, so I would dump the paid plan and work out any concerns with Apple developer relations if and when they have any problem with your account.